# How to get a handle of a new stage Controller JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, controller, scene

I am starting a 2nd scene that uses it's own controller. I want to access a method within that controller from another class. How can I get a handle of the new scene controller?

```
public void startNewScene() throws IOException{
     Stage stage = new Stage();
     Partent root;
     root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxmlfile.fxml");
     Scene scene = new Scene(root);
     Stage.setScene(scene);
     stage.show();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an `FXMLLoader` instance (instead of using the *static* `load(...)` method), and get the controller from it:

```
public void startNewScene() throws IOException{
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("fxmlfile.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    MyController controller = loader.getController();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    Stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Obviously replace `MyController` with the actual class name of the controller for `fxmlfile.fxml`.

Comment: I am getting ClassCastException AnchorPane Cannot be cast to FXMLLoader. I also changed it to BorderPane, i am getting the same error can't be cast to FXMLLoader

Comment: you are right!! instead of doing new FXMLLoader(getClass()) i did FXMLLoader.load(getClass()); thx for your help!!!